# Is NAT completely transparent to a host?

Tags: nat

Can we find a sequence of packets that a host can transmit to determine whether it is located behind a NAT box?

I mean, without any special server support like STUN.

Comment: If it were possible to do it without STUN, why would we have need for STUN in the first place?

Comment: STUN servers give the external IP to the client. It is possible with lots of protocols to determine that nat is being used without having to fallback to a stun server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if your interface has a RFC 1918 private address but you can still reach common Internet hosts, your host is behind a NAT somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't unless the opposite end-point (call it B) purposefully (or not) include a reference to the IP of its peer (call it A). Another requirement on top of the aforementioned is that point B must not be using NAT itself.

In short, you either need the assistance of a standard/non-standard server (e.g. STUN or "home-made) or a leak in the communication abstraction. The latter should be considered a design flaw and considered unreliable (at some point somebody will probably *fix it*).

Comment: Indeed - the whole point is that the host shouldn't notice, and most NAT implementations rewrite as much as possible to make this the case. There are protocols that **do** expose the IP and aren't as commonly rewritten (e.g. SIP, some P2P, anything encrypted) but I suspect this might be considered "server support" ;)

Comment: @SimonJ: 100% agree. It is unfortunate but such leaks do occur. We must remember that NAT is a big "bandaid that shouldn't exist" from an architectural point of view... of course, money$ comes first and we needed ways to enhance security & multiple IPv4 end-points, hence NAT.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it can be done using the TTL field in the IP packets: http://www.sflow.org/detectNAT/.

Comment: Not all firewalls touch TTL. On Cisco PIX/ASA, this is actually a configurable option.

Comment: I don't think this helps - it's for detecting NAT routers on your network that are "hiding" other hosts behind them, whereas the OP wants to know whether the host itself is behind NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. As far as I know, there's no real way to tell if NAT is being used.